# Reading CSV file based to the condition

Tags: python, csv

My csv file is like this

```
Despription,Car, Deminsion,, 
length,5677,
height,3797,
width,6883,
Engine,,
cc,2000,
power,65,
Break,,
rear,disc,
front,disc,
```

I want extract rows between Deminsion and engine and put them in to a variable,and rows between Engine and Break to another variable.
I have been trying it with python csv.
Can anyone figure a way out?

Comment: And what have you tried? (please read [ask]...)

Comment: Your CSV is non-sensical. Why are you having three more columns that are never used in the file? I'm guessing the 'Deminsion' (a typo, btw.) should be on a new line, right? Also, those column names make no sense whatsoever...

Comment: yes, The dimension is the new row.

Comment: I'm getting the values row wise. I want to extract the particular columns .

Comment: I want to extract the particular section in the columns . The condition is to get data between dimensions and Engine ,  engine and brake. This is just an example column. The original data is huge to put it here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement that logic, program won't be able to do it via configurational attributes. Implement the circle with bag-functions

```
# Pattern identification list
store = {'Deminsion': [], 'Engine': []}
# Default / initial pattern
target = 'Deminsion'

with open('data1.txt') as csvFile:
# Create a list of parameters
dataList = [line.split() for line in csvFile]        
# Process the list 
for i,x in enumerate(dataList):
    if i == 0:
        continue 
    x=x.split()
    if x[0] in store:
        target = x[0]
    else:
        store[target].append(x)
```